# Is there a solution, allowing to fill a string field by decoding the bar code?

Tags: 8

Do you know if is there a solution which would allow to input data to a string field decoding an image with bar code ?

That is, there is a field, containing a button. Having pressed at the button, I upload an image with bar code, which immediately is decoded and received value (string, number and so on) is placed in the field. And beside that the field can be filled manually, with keyboard.

Or, is there a simular solution ?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I have asked this question because I negotiate with potential client on a freelance site and he wants to do it. And I have decided to assess the situation and look around existing solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no quick fix for this for Drupal 8. The only thing that comes near for Drupal 7 is the [Commerce Barcode Scanner](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_barcode_scanner) module.

If you're willing to get your hands dirty, I can advice this Q: [Reading barcode from an image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869445/reading-barcode-from-an-image-using-javascript).

**tl;dr**

Implement one of these three javascript libraries:

- https://gist.github.com/tobytailor/421369
- https://github.com/EddieLa/JOB
- https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/